# How to call function inside function in ionic3?

Tags: angular, ionic3

How to call function inside function in ionic3 i have tried with this function but not working and i got error in console '=>' expected tell me anyone how to fix this?

```js
shareProductWithSelectedUser(event) {
  var self = this;
  var  arr1 = "";
  var  arr2 = "";
  var  arr3 = "";

  // Iterating loop - continue only after callback from Firerbase.
    var x = 0;
    var loopArray(arr1, arr2, arr3) {

    // here calling inner function for share product with three param(userId, userTypeId, callback)
    self.callFuncForShareProduct(arr1[x], arr2[x], arr3[x], (function) =>  {
       // any more items in array? continue loop
        if(x < arr1.length) {
          this.loopArray(arr1, arr2, arr3);
         };
      });
      // start 'loop'
      loopArray(self.userIdListForShareProduct, self.userTypeIdListForShareProduct, self.userObjectListForShare);
    }
```

Comment: Very confusing code. Is loopArray a recursive function? And what is shareProductWithSelectedUser?

Comment: i have call 3 function one  by one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So first let's simplify your code

```
executeFunction(event) {
  var self = this;

  var innerFunction(args) {

      self.doSomething('somevariable', (function) =>  {
        if(/* expression */) {
          this.innerFunction(args);
         };
      });

      doAnotherFunction();
    }
}
```

So, you create a function, with an inner function and want the innerfunction to call itself and also call another function outside of the scope.

Now. The problems.

- `function` is a reserved keyword and can't be used like that in a lambda.
- creating an inner function doesn't work like that. Use `function innerFunction(args)` or `var innerFunction = (args) => {}`

You can rewrite your code with both of the methods in the second bullet point. I'll show you an example for the lambda.

```
executeFunction(event) {
  var innerFunction = (args) => {

      // the lambda allows you to keep the original scope, so you can still use `this`
      this.doSomething('somevariable', () =>  {
        if(/* expression */) {

           // innerFunction isn't defined globally but scope is maintained so you can call it like so
          innerFunction(args);
         };
      });

      this.doAnotherFunction();
    }
}
```

So after doing a double take on your code I'm not sure if you're creating an inner function but the code above should solve your other issues as well.

Comment: Please do note that calling `executeFunction` only creates the inner function but doesn't execute it. If you want to execute, add `innerFunction(someArgs);` before the closing tag of `executeFunction`

Comment: thank you sir for this information regarding to the inner function and i try this  code and its woking for me